# Error cocos3d + Storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos3d, xcode6.4

I did an Example like CC3DemoMultiScene in iOS objective-c, I follow the same code thing like in example

my AppDelegate follows:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{return YES;
}

-(void) applicationWillResignActive: (UIApplication*) application {
    [CCDirector.sharedDirector pause];
}

-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive: (UIApplication*) application {
    [CCDirector.sharedDirector resume];
}

-(void) applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning: (UIApplication*) application {
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground: (UIApplication*) application {
    [CCDirector.sharedDirector stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground: (UIApplication*) application {
    [CCDirector.sharedDirector startAnimation];
}

-(void)applicationWillTerminate: (UIApplication*) application {
    [CC3OpenGL terminateOpenGL];
}

-(void) applicationSignificantTimeChange: (UIApplication*) application {
    [CCDirector.sharedDirector setNextDeltaTimeZero: YES];
}

@end
```

there is not any error meanwhile compile, but when run in iOS Simulator, the App Crashes print me this issues:

```
2015-08-14 16:43:26.446 ExampleCocos3d[9063:116836] *** Assertion failure in GLint CompileShader(GLenum, const char *)(), /Users/Dennis/Desktop/ExampleCocos3d/Libraries/DennisCocos3D/cocos2d/cocos2d/cocos2d/CCShader.m:173
2015-08-14 16:43:26.462 ExampleCocos3d[9063:116836] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error compiling shader'


  *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edc6c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e642bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edc6aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
        3   Foundation                          0x000000010e149a57 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 169
        4   ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010aab3d0c CompileShader + 364
        5   ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010aab3964 -[CCShader initWithVertexShaderSource:fragmentShaderSource:] + 212
        6   ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010aab3ebd -[CCShader initWithFragmentShaderSource:] + 77
        7   ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010aab40d4 +[CCShader initialize] + 180
        8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e6434d6 _class_initialize + 648
        9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e64c6e1 lookUpImpOrForward + 351
        10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e6590d3 objc_msgSend + 211
        11  ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010aabd331 -[CCRenderer init] + 353
        12  ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010ade7c1b -[CCDirector init] + 875
        13  ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010ad6e266 -[CCDirectorIOS init] + 54
        14  ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010ade7760 +[CCDirector sharedDirector] + 144
        15  ExampleCocos3d                      0x000000010ace34bd -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] + 61
        16  UIKit                               0x000000010c2b92ce -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 313
        17  UIKit                               0x000000010c2ce417 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:] + 2589
        18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112a845e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecfa41c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecf0165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eceff25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecef366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
        23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011071ca3e GSEventRunModal + 161
        24  UIKit                               0x000000010c2be900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
        25  Tripsland                           0x000000010ad63b4f main + 111
        26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f465145 start + 1
        27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
                //------------------------------------------//
                //               THANKS GUYS                //
                //          GRETTINGS FROM BOLIVIA          //
                //             ROCK ON!!!! n_n'             //
                //------------------------------------------//
```

please help!! or exist any error in the CCShader.m file from Cocos2D Library, the error is generated in:

```
static GLint
CompileShader(GLenum type, const char *source)
{
    GLint shader = glCreateShader(type);

    const GLchar *sources[] = {
        CCShaderHeader,
        CCShaderTypeHeader(type),
        source,
    };

    glShaderSource(shader, 3, sources, NULL);

    glCompileShader(shader);

    NSCAssert(CCCheckShaderError(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, glGetShaderiv, glGetShaderInfoLog), @"Error compiling shader");

    return shader;
}
```

**FIRST EDIT:** thanks for the recommendation ***user2242300***

well the ***.h*** and ***.m*** files from ***CCShader*** are in the

```
cocos2d-library-iOS.xcodeproj/cocos2d/cocos2d/CCShader.h
cocos2d-library-iOS.xcodeproj/cocos2d/cocos2d/CCShader.m
```

the ***CCShader.h*** file have:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ccTypes.h"
#import "ccMacros.h"
#import "Platforms/CCGL.h"

/// Macro to embed GLSL source
#define CC_GLSL(x) @#x


extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformProjection;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformProjectionInv;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformViewSize;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformViewSizeInPixels;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformTime;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformSinTime;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformCosTime;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformRandom01;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformMainTexture;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformNormalMapTexture;
extern const NSString *CCShaderUniformAlphaTestValue;


@interface CCShader : NSObject<NSCopying>

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *debugName;

+(instancetype)shaderNamed:(NSString *)shaderName;

-(instancetype)initWithVertexShaderSource:(NSString *)vertexSource fragmentShaderSource:(NSString *)fragmentSource;
-(instancetype)initWithFragmentShaderSource:(NSString *)source;

+(instancetype)positionColorShader;
+(instancetype)positionTextureColorShader;
+(instancetype)positionTextureColorAlphaTestShader;
+(instancetype)positionTextureA8ColorShader;

@end
```

and the ***CCShader.m*** have:

```
#import "CCShader_private.h"
#import "ccMacros.h"
#import "Support/CCFileUtils.h"
#import "Support/uthash.h"
#import "CCRenderer_private.h"
#import "CCTexture_private.h"
#import "CCDirector.h"
#import "CCCache.h"
#import "CCGL.h"


enum {
    CCAttributePosition,
    CCAttributeTexCoord1,
    CCAttributeTexCoord2,
    CCAttributeColor,
};


const NSString *CCShaderUniformProjection = @"cc_Projection";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformProjectionInv = @"cc_ProjectionInv";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformViewSize = @"cc_ViewSize";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformViewSizeInPixels = @"cc_ViewSizeInPixels";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformTime = @"cc_Time";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformSinTime = @"cc_SinTime";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformCosTime = @"cc_CosTime";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformRandom01 = @"cc_Random01";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformMainTexture = @"cc_MainTexture";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformNormalMapTexture = @"cc_NormalMapTexture";
const NSString *CCShaderUniformAlphaTestValue = @"cc_AlphaTestValue";


// Stringify macros
#define STR(s) #s
#define XSTR(s) STR(s)

/*
    main texture size points/pixels?
*/
static const GLchar *CCShaderHeader =
    "#ifndef GL_ES\n"
    "#define lowp\n"
    "#define mediump\n"
    "#define highp\n"
    "#endif\n\n"
    "uniform highp mat4 cc_Projection;\n"
    "uniform highp mat4 cc_ProjectionInv;\n"
    "uniform highp vec2 cc_ViewSize;\n"
    "uniform highp vec2 cc_ViewSizeInPixels;\n"
    "uniform highp vec4 cc_Time;\n"
    "uniform highp vec4 cc_SinTime;\n"
    "uniform highp vec4 cc_CosTime;\n"
    "uniform highp vec4 cc_Random01;\n\n"
    "uniform " XSTR(CC_SHADER_COLOR_PRECISION) " sampler2D cc_MainTexture;\n\n"
    "uniform " XSTR(CC_SHADER_COLOR_PRECISION) " sampler2D cc_NormalMapTexture;\n\n"
    "varying " XSTR(CC_SHADER_COLOR_PRECISION) " vec4 cc_FragColor;\n"
    "varying highp vec2 cc_FragTexCoord1;\n"
    "varying highp vec2 cc_FragTexCoord2;\n\n"
    "// End Cocos2D shader header.\n\n";

static const GLchar *CCVertexShaderHeader =
    "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
    "precision highp float;\n\n"
    "#endif\n\n"
    "#define CC_NODE_RENDER_SUBPIXEL " XSTR(CC_NODE_RENDER_SUBPIXEL) "\n"
    "attribute highp vec4 cc_Position;\n"
    "attribute highp vec2 cc_TexCoord1;\n"
    "attribute highp vec2 cc_TexCoord2;\n"
    "attribute highp vec4 cc_Color;\n\n"
    "// End Cocos2D vertex shader header.\n\n";

static const GLchar *CCFragmentShaderHeader =
    "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
    "precision " XSTR(CC_SHADER_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_PRECISION) " float;\n"
    "#endif\n\n"
    "// End Cocos2D fragment shader header.\n\n";

static NSString *CCDefaultVShader =
    @"void main(){\n"
    @"  gl_Position = cc_Position;\n"
    @"#if !CC_NODE_RENDER_SUBPIXEL\n"
    @"  vec2 pixelPos = (0.5*gl_Position.xy/gl_Position.w + 0.5)*cc_ViewSizeInPixels;\n"
    @"  gl_Position.xy = (2.0*floor(pixelPos)/cc_ViewSizeInPixels - 1.0)*gl_Position.w;\n"
    @"#endif\n\n"
    @"  cc_FragColor = clamp(cc_Color, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    @"  cc_FragTexCoord1 = cc_TexCoord1;\n"
    @"  cc_FragTexCoord2 = cc_TexCoord2;\n"
    @"}\n";

typedef void (* GetShaderivFunc) (GLuint shader, GLenum pname, GLint* param);
typedef void (* GetShaderInfoLogFunc) (GLuint shader, GLsizei bufSize, GLsizei* length, GLchar* infoLog);

static BOOL
CCCheckShaderError(GLint obj, GLenum status, GetShaderivFunc getiv, GetShaderInfoLogFunc getInfoLog)
{
    GLint success;
    getiv(obj, status, &success);

    if(!success){
        GLint length;
        getiv(obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

        char *log = (char *)alloca(length);
        getInfoLog(obj, length, NULL, log);

        fprintf(stderr, "Shader compile error for 0x%04X: %s\n", status, log);
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

static const GLchar *
CCShaderTypeHeader(GLenum type)
{
    switch(type){
        case GL_VERTEX_SHADER: return CCVertexShaderHeader;
        case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER: return CCFragmentShaderHeader;
        default: NSCAssert(NO, @"Bad shader type enumeration."); return NULL;
    }
}

static GLint
CompileShader(GLenum type, const char *source)
{
    GLint shader = glCreateShader(type);

    const GLchar *sources[] = {
        CCShaderHeader,
        CCShaderTypeHeader(type),
        source,
    };

    glShaderSource(shader, 3, sources, NULL);

    glCompileShader(shader);

    NSCAssert(CCCheckShaderError(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, glGetShaderiv, glGetShaderInfoLog), @"Error compiling shader");

    return shader;
}


@interface CCShaderCache : CCCache @end
@implementation CCShaderCache

-(id)createSharedDataForKey:(id<NSCopying>)key
{
    NSString *shaderName = (NSString *)key;

    NSString *fragmentName = [shaderName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"fsh"];
    NSString *fragmentPath = [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] fullPathForFilename:fragmentName];
    NSAssert(fragmentPath, @"Failed to find '%@'.", fragmentName);
    NSString *fragmentSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fragmentPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSString *vertexName = [shaderName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"vsh"];
    NSString *vertexPath = [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] fullPathForFilename:vertexName];
    NSString *vertexSource = (vertexPath ? [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:vertexPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] : CCDefaultVShader);

    CCShader *shader = [[CCShader alloc] initWithVertexShaderSource:vertexSource fragmentShaderSource:fragmentSource];
    shader.debugName = @"shaderName";

    return shader;
}

-(id)createPublicObjectForSharedData:(id)data
{
    return [data copy];
}

@end


@implementation CCShader {
    BOOL _ownsProgram;
}

+(GLuint)createVAOforCCVertexBuffer:(GLuint)vbo elementBuffer:(GLuint)ebo
{
    glPushGroupMarkerEXT(0, "CCShader: Creating vertex buffer");

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(CCAttributePosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(CCAttributeTexCoord1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(CCAttributeTexCoord2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(CCAttributeColor);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(CCAttributePosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CCVertex), (void *)offsetof(CCVertex, position));
    glVertexAttribPointer(CCAttributeTexCoord1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CCVertex), (void *)offsetof(CCVertex, texCoord1));
    glVertexAttribPointer(CCAttributeTexCoord2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CCVertex), (void *)offsetof(CCVertex, texCoord2));
    glVertexAttribPointer(CCAttributeColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CCVertex), (void *)offsetof(CCVertex, color));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glPopGroupMarkerEXT();

    return vao;
}

//MARK: Uniform Setters:

static CCUniformSetter
SetFloat(NSString *name, GLint location)
{
    return ^(CCRenderer *renderer, NSDictionary *shaderUniforms, NSDictionary *globalShaderUniforms){
        NSNumber *value = shaderUniforms[name] ?: globalShaderUniforms[name] ?: @(0.0);
        NSCAssert([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]], @"Shader uniform '%@' value must be wrapped in a NSNumber.", name);

        glUniform1f(location, value.floatValue);
    };
}

static CCUniformSetter
SetVec2(NSString *name, GLint location)
{
    NSString *textureName = nil;
    bool pixelSize = [name hasSuffix:@"PixelSize"];
    if(pixelSize){
        textureName = [name substringToIndex:name.length - @"PixelSize".length];
    } else if([name hasSuffix:@"Size"]){
        textureName = [name substringToIndex:name.length - @"Size".length];
    }

    return ^(CCRenderer *renderer, NSDictionary *shaderUniforms, NSDictionary *globalShaderUniforms){
        NSValue *value = shaderUniforms[name] ?: globalShaderUniforms[name];

        // Fall back on looking up the actual texture size if the name matches a texture.
        if(value == nil && textureName){
            CCTexture *texture = shaderUniforms[textureName] ?: globalShaderUniforms[textureName];
            GLKVector2 sizeInPixels = GLKVector2Make(texture.pixelWidth, texture.pixelHeight);

            GLKVector2 size = GLKVector2MultiplyScalar(sizeInPixels, pixelSize ? 1.0 : 1.0/texture.contentScale);
            value = [NSValue valueWithGLKVector2:size];
        }

        // Finally fall back on 0.
        if(value == nil) value = [NSValue valueWithGLKVector2:GLKVector2Make(0.0f, 0.0f)];

        NSCAssert([value isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]], @"Shader uniform '%@' value must be wrapped in a NSValue.", name);

        if(strcmp(value.objCType, @encode(GLKVector2)) == 0){
            GLKVector2 v; [value getValue:&v];
            glUniform2f(location, v.x, v.y);
        } else if(strcmp(value.objCType, @encode(CGPoint)) == 0){
            CGPoint v = {}; [value getValue:&v];
            glUniform2f(location, v.x, v.y);
        } else if(strcmp(value.objCType, @encode(CGSize)) == 0){
            CGSize v = {}; [value getValue:&v];
            glUniform2f(location, v.width, v.height);
        } else {
            NSCAssert(NO, @"Shader uniformm 'vec2 %@' value must be passed using [NSValue valueWithGLKVector2:], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:], or [NSValue valueWithCGSize:]", name);
        }
    };
}

static CCUniformSetter
SetVec3(NSString *name, GLint location)
{
    return ^(CCRenderer *renderer, NSDictionary *shaderUniforms, NSDictionary *globalShaderUniforms){
        NSValue *value = shaderUniforms[name] ?: globalShaderUniforms[name] ?: [NSValue valueWithGLKVector3:GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
        NSCAssert([value isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]], @"Shader uniform '%@' value must be wrapped in a NSValue.", name);
        NSCAssert(strcmp(value.objCType, @encode(GLKVector3)) == 0, @"Shader uniformm 'vec3 %@' value must be passed using [NSValue valueWithGLKVector3:]", name);

        GLKVector3 v; [value getValue:&v];
        glUniform3f(location, v.x, v.y, v.z);
    };
}

static CCUniformSetter
SetVec4(NSString *name, GLint location)
{
    return ^(CCRenderer *renderer, NSDictionary *shaderUniforms, NSDictionary *globalShaderUniforms){
        NSValue *value = shaderUniforms[name] ?: globalShaderUniforms[name] ?: [NSValue valueWithGLKVector4:GLKVector4Make(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];

        if([value isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]]){
            NSCAssert(strcmp([(NSValue *)value objCType], @encode(GLKVector4)) == 0, @"Shader uniformm 'vec4 %@' value must be passed using [NSValue valueWithGLKVector4:].", name);

            GLKVector4 v; [value getValue:&v];
            glUniform4f(location, v.x, v.y, v.z, v.w);
        } else if([value isKindOfClass:[CCColor class]]){
            GLKVector4 v = [(CCColor *)value glkVector4];
            glUniform4f(location, v.x, v.y, v.z, v.w);
        } else {
            NSCAssert(NO, @"Shader uniformm 'vec4 %@' value must be passed using [NSValue valueWithGLKVector4:] or a CCColor object.", name);
        }
    };
}

static CCUniformSetter
SetMat4(NSString *name, GLint location)
{
    return ^(CCRenderer *renderer, NSDictionary *shaderUniforms, NSDictionary *globalShaderUniforms){
        NSValue *value = shaderUniforms[name] ?: globalShaderUniforms[name] ?: [NSValue valueWithGLKMatrix4:GLKMatrix4Identity];
        NSCAssert([value isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]], @"Shader uniform '%@' value must be wrapped in a NSValue.", name);
        NSCAssert(strcmp(value.objCType, @encode(GLKMatrix4)) == 0, @"Shader uniformm 'mat4 %@' value must be passed using [NSValue valueWithGLKMatrix4:]", name);

        GLKMatrix4 m; [value getValue:&m];
        glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, m.m);
    };
}

-(NSDictionary *)uniformSettersForProgram:(GLuint)program
{
    NSMutableDictionary *uniformSetters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    glUseProgram(program);

    GLint count = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &count);

    int textureUnit = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        GLchar cname[256];
        GLsizei length = 0;
        GLsizei size = 0;
        GLenum type = 0;

        glGetActiveUniform(program, i, sizeof(cname), &length, &size, &type, cname);
        NSAssert(size == 1, @"Uniform arrays not supported. (yet?)");

        NSString *name = @(cname);
        GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(program, cname);

        // Setup a block that is responsible for binding that uniform variable's value.
        switch(type){
            default: NSAssert(NO, @"Uniform type not supported. (yet?)");
            case GL_FLOAT: uniformSetters[name] = SetFloat(name, location); break;
            case GL_FLOAT_VEC2: uniformSetters[name] = SetVec2(name, location); break;
            case GL_FLOAT_VEC3: uniformSetters[name] = SetVec3(name, location); break;
            case GL_FLOAT_VEC4: uniformSetters[name] = SetVec4(name, location); break;
            case GL_FLOAT_MAT4: uniformSetters[name] = SetMat4(name, location); break;
            case GL_SAMPLER_2D: {
                // Sampler setters are handled a differently since the real work is binding the texture and not setting the uniform value.
                uniformSetters[name] = ^(CCRenderer *renderer, NSDictionary *shaderUniforms, NSDictionary *globalShaderUniforms){
                    CCTexture *texture = shaderUniforms[name] ?: globalShaderUniforms[name] ?: [CCTexture none];
                    NSAssert([texture isKindOfClass:[CCTexture class]], @"Shader uniform '%@' value must be a CCTexture object.", name);

                    // Bind the texture to the texture unit for the uniform.
                    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + textureUnit);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.name);
                };

                // Bind the texture unit at init time.
                glUniform1i(location, textureUnit);
                textureUnit++;
            }
        }
    }

    return uniformSetters;
}

//MARK: Init Methods:

-(instancetype)initWithProgram:(GLuint)program uniformSetters:(NSDictionary *)uniformSetters ownsProgram:(BOOL)ownsProgram
{
    if((self = [super init])){
        _program = program;
        _uniformSetters = uniformSetters;
        _ownsProgram = ownsProgram;
    }

    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithVertexShaderSource:(NSString *)vertexSource fragmentShaderSource:(NSString *)fragmentSource
{
    glPushGroupMarkerEXT(0, "CCShader: Init");

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glBindAttribLocation(program, CCAttributePosition, "cc_Position");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, CCAttributeTexCoord1, "cc_TexCoord1");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, CCAttributeTexCoord2, "cc_TexCoord2");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, CCAttributeColor, "cc_Color");

    GLint vshader = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource.UTF8String);
    glAttachShader(program, vshader);

    GLint fshader = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource.UTF8String);
    glAttachShader(program, fshader);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    NSCAssert(CCCheckShaderError(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, glGetProgramiv, glGetProgramInfoLog), @"Error linking shader program");

    glDeleteShader(vshader);
    glDeleteShader(fshader);

    glPopGroupMarkerEXT();

    return [self initWithProgram:program uniformSetters:[self uniformSettersForProgram:program] ownsProgram:YES];
}

-(instancetype)initWithFragmentShaderSource:(NSString *)source
{
    return [self initWithVertexShaderSource:CCDefaultVShader fragmentShaderSource:source];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    CCLOGINFO( @"cocos2d: deallocing %@", self);

    if(_ownsProgram && _program) glDeleteProgram(_program);
}

-(instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[CCShader allocWithZone:zone] initWithProgram:_program uniformSetters:_uniformSetters ownsProgram:NO];
}

static CCShaderCache *CC_SHADER_CACHE = nil;
static CCShader *CC_SHADER_POS_COLOR = nil;
static CCShader *CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR = nil;
static CCShader *CC_SHADER_POS_TEXA8_COLOR = nil;
static CCShader *CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR_ALPHA_TEST = nil;

+(void)initialize
{
    // +initialize may be called due to loading a subclass.
    if(self != [CCShader class]) return;

    CC_SHADER_CACHE = [[CCShaderCache alloc] init];

    // Setup the builtin shaders.
    CC_SHADER_POS_COLOR = [[self alloc] initWithFragmentShaderSource:@"void main(){gl_FragColor = cc_FragColor;}"];
    CC_SHADER_POS_COLOR.debugName = @"CCPositionColorShader";

    CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR = [[self alloc] initWithFragmentShaderSource:@"void main(){gl_FragColor = cc_FragColor*texture2D(cc_MainTexture, cc_FragTexCoord1);}"];
    CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR.debugName = @"CCPositionTextureColorShader";

    CC_SHADER_POS_TEXA8_COLOR = [[self alloc] initWithFragmentShaderSource:@"void main(){gl_FragColor = cc_FragColor*texture2D(cc_MainTexture, cc_FragTexCoord1).a;}"];
    CC_SHADER_POS_TEXA8_COLOR.debugName = @"CCPositionTextureA8ColorShader";

    CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR_ALPHA_TEST = [[self alloc] initWithFragmentShaderSource:CC_GLSL(
        uniform float cc_AlphaTestValue;
        void main(){
            vec4 tex = texture2D(cc_MainTexture, cc_FragTexCoord1);
            if(tex.a <= cc_AlphaTestValue) discard;
            gl_FragColor = cc_FragColor*tex;
        }
    )];
    CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR_ALPHA_TEST.debugName = @"CCPositionTextureColorAlphaTestShader";
}

+(instancetype)positionColorShader
{
    return CC_SHADER_POS_COLOR;
}

+(instancetype)positionTextureColorShader
{
    return CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR;
}

+(instancetype)positionTextureColorAlphaTestShader
{
    return CC_SHADER_POS_TEX_COLOR_ALPHA_TEST;
}

+(instancetype)positionTextureA8ColorShader
{
    return CC_SHADER_POS_TEXA8_COLOR;
}

+(instancetype)shaderNamed:(NSString *)shaderName
{
    return [CC_SHADER_CACHE objectForKey:shaderName];
}

@end
```

you can get the example code from:[cocos3d](https://github.com/cocos3d/cocos3d) following: the ***CC3DemoMultiScene*** in [File Projects](https://github.com/cocos3d/cocos3d/tree/master/Projects)

**SECOND EDIT:**

I read several responses on StackOverflow and in this forum: [Cocos 2D Forum](http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/), I had to re install xCode, I don't know what happened? but now, not show me the CCShader Error, show me:

```
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION detected at -[CCRenderer(NoARCPrivate) setRenderState:] 232
```

how is the best way for show 1 Scene of Cocos 3D in 2 different ViewControllers?

Thanks Again!!

Comment: It looks like the error is in the shader´s code, not in your app code. Are you sure you are providing the code for the shaders? For OpenGL ES you must have at least 2 source codes for the shaders, one for a vertex shader and one for a fragment shader. If in fact you do have that source code, please update the question with it so we can check for errors there.

Comment: @user_Dennis_Mostajo have you ever solved this issue? I have some much pain with this as well

Comment: @VladMiller I just answered, I hope you serve and I shared a link to my project, regards! XD

Answer (score 1):

After of many searches and investigations, The reason this causes trouble is because this causes the AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive: method (which references CCDirector.sharedDirector singleton) to be invoked before the MainViewController createGLView method (which initializes the CCDirector.sharedDirector singleton).

The reference to the uninitialized CCDirector.sharedDirector singleton in AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive: triggers a whole bunch of Cocos2D OpenGL ES initialization before the OpenGL context has been set up correctly, causing a bunch of shader loading activity to fail.

The best way to fix this is to ensure that the code found in the MainViewController createGLView method is run before any references to the CCDirector.sharedDirector singleton are made elsewhere.

We can also side-step the problem in the short-term by commenting out the code in the AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive: method, but that might affect the behaviour of your app as it moves in and out of the background.

like the answers from [@Bill Hollings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678054/bill-hollings) in this questions:
[Error CompileShader in Xcode 7.1.1 on iOS 9?](http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/t/error-compileshader-in-xcode-7-1-1-on-ios-9/17771) and
[Error cocos3d + Storyboard?](http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/t/error-cocos3d-storyboard/17515/3)

I configured and tried an example [DennisCocos3D Prueba](https://www.dropbox.com/s/efh8jr9uosh2hw4/DennisCocos3dStory.zip?dl=0) (dropbox)

or try with:

in MainViewController .m file:

```
 -(CCGLView*) createGLView {

    // Create the view first, since it creates the GL context, which CCDirector expects during init.
    CCGLView* glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame: _cc3FrameView.bounds
                                   pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat: GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8     // Shadow volumes require a stencil
                            preserveBackbuffer: NO
                               numberOfSamples: 1];



    CCDirector* director = CCDirector.sharedDirector;
    director.animationInterval = (1.0f / kAnimationFrameRate);
    director.displayStats = YES;
    director.view = glView;

    // Run the initial static 2D intro scene
    [director runWithScene: [[self makeIntroScene] asCCScene]];

    if(![[CCDirector sharedDirector]  runningScene])
    {

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[[self makeIntroScene] asCCScene]];
    }
    else
    {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];


        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[[self makeIntroScene] asCCScene]];
    }

    return glView;
}
```